# Inline java works, but c:if does not

Tags: jsp

Below produces output of 'true' which means the attribute is set.
But why does neither c:if output the "Login failed" h2 tag?

```
<%
    if (session.getAttribute("loginFail") != null)
        out.write(session.getAttribute("loginFail").toString());
%>
<c:if test='${session.getAttribute("loginFail") != null}'>
    <h2>Login failed</h2>
</c:if>
<c:if test='${session.getAttribute("loginFail") == true}'>
    <h2>Login failed</h2>
</c:if>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/tags/el/info - try using `${not empty session...}`

Comment: Actually, that should be ${not empty loginFail} Then it works. Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The session attributes are accessible to JSP without session qualifier:

```
<c:if test="${not empty loginFail)}">
    <h2>Login failed</h2>
</c:if>
```